# DispatcherTimer Array problem

Tags: vb.net

At the moment, I have the following code: 
Public tmr() As DispatcherTimer

```
Public Sub CreateTimer(ByVal timernumber As Integer)
    Dim main As New MainWindow

    Dim tmr(timernumber) As DispatcherTimer
    tmr(timernumber - 1).Stop()
    tmr(timernumber).Start()
    tmr(timernumber).Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50)

    AddHandler tmr(timernumber).Tick, AddressOf main.tmr_tick
End Sub


Public Sub CreateFirstTimer(ByVal timernumber As Integer)
    Dim main As New MainWindow

    Dim tmr(timernumber) As DispatcherTimer
    tmr(timernumber).Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50)
    tmr(timernumber).Start()
    AddHandler tmr(timernumber).Tick, AddressOf main.tmr_tick
End Sub
```

This is part of a slightly Object - Oriented application, and two subroutines feed this class with a variable 'timernumber'. This all looks like it should work, however, when the application goes to use these subroutines, it crashes, as the Dim tmr(timernumber) As DispatcherTimer doesn't have a "new" statement in it (As New DispatcherTimer). When I put a "New" in, VB complains about not being able to use the New keyword with an array. 
So, I suppose how can I dynamically create dispatchertimers in WPF, all of which work? And perhaps "delete" the old ones on the way?
Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `tmr` declared somewhere else? If so you want to use:

```
tmr(timernumber) = New DispatcherTimer()
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea how I missed that, yes, Dim tmr() As DispatcherTimer is set globally above these subroutines. Thank you!